# The plugin `flutter_ringtone_player` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, ringtone

I am using Flutter 2.6.0-6.0.pre.2 • channel master,Android SDK version 31.0.0 and Dart 2.15.0 (build 2.15.0-82.0.dev) but when I used flutter_ringtone_player: ^3.0.0

I found deprecated error, please help me to sort it out. please see the bellow error details.

**This is the error message:**

> The plugin `flutter_ringtone_player` uses a deprecated version of the Android
> embedding.
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if
> this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it
> since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
> If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to
> the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

how to use Android V2 embedding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
flutter_ringtone_player:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/aarajput/flutter_ringtone_player.git
      ref: 'issue/android_v2_embedding'
```

Someone migrated the plugin to V2 but you have to reference it like this since the plugin hasn't been updated

Answer (score 0):

The package you are using "flutter_ringtone_player" doesn't support V2 as the error message says.

You can't solve the error because you are not the maintainer or writer of this package. The person who is managing it should be responsible to migrate it.

The best option would be to go for another package.

Comment: can you please  help me which package is good for ringtone

Comment: This should work.  I checked it. https://pub.dev/packages/ringtone_player